# Recurso para grabar la pantalla y guardarlo en formato GIF

Tags: discusión, recursos

Revisando preguntas me doy cuenta que hay algo que podría ser de utilidad y quisiera saber que opinan de ello: agregar un gif con el error que pasa.

Aquí les comparto esta herramienta gratuita y sencilla para grabar la pantalla al estilo de un corto video en formato gif:

**[ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/)**

Lo bonito de esta herramienta es que el archivo es ligero.

Comment: Gracias por la info, va a favs

Comment: de nada, seguimos creciendo :)

Comment: Muy util, gracias fredyfx

Comment: Buen aporte, aunque solo sea para Güindous T_T

Comment: Para Mac existe Giphy que también es bastante sencilla.

Comment: No la conocía y me va a venir genial, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Me parece de muy buena utilidad para preguntas que son difíciles de entender viendo solamente el código, por ejemplo interfaces de usuario que no estén en HTML (ya que no se puede incrustar como stack snippet). Sin embargo considero que no se debe abusar cuando realmente no es necesario y basta con el texto y código.

Por mi son bienvenidos el uso de gifs y la herramienta propuesta por [**fredyfx**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/822/fredyfx) y otras similares. Las únicas observaciones que tengo (y que no trata de la herramienta en sí, sino el uso de los gifs) son:

- Los gifs deben ser **adicionales** al contenido en **texto y código** de la pregunta (como cualquier otra imagen) y no la única referencia para entender el problema.
- Deben subirse como cualquier otra imagen incrustada en la pregunta (bajo el dominio https://i.stack.imgur.com/) y no un link a otra fuente externa.

Ejemplo de `.gif` en pregunta (sacado del link de github):

[image: Gif sacado de la página de Screentogif]

Comment: lastima que no se puede pausar... @#$$#$%#

Comment: @rnd tiene un editor, me parece que si se puede

Comment: Solo funciona para la comunidad. Para los otros servicios como los Team ya no funciona el gif.